# Automatically refreshing yii2 grid after server database changes

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a grid that involves truck verification. I would like the contents of the grid to change without page refresh.

Currently this works when the page is refreshed but i would like it to work even when a page is not refreshed that is when the content changes in the server database.

This is the grid

```
<?php

$gridColumns = [
 ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
  'reg_no',
 [
    'attribute'=>'truck_category',
    'value'=>'truckCategory.category'
 ],

 [
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
    'vAlign'=>'middle',
    'urlCreator' => function($action, $model, $key, $index) { return '#'; },
    'viewOptions'=>['title'=>"vdgdv", 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip'],
    'updateOptions'=>['title'=>"update", 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip'],
    'deleteOptions'=>['title'=>"delete", 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip'],
   ]
];


echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => $gridColumns,
'containerOptions' => ['style'=>'overflow: auto'], // only set when $responsive = false
'beforeHeader'=>[
    [
       'options'=>['class'=>'skip-export'] // remove this row from export
    ]
],
'toolbar' =>  [
    [],
    '{export}',
    '{toggleData}'
],
'pjax' => true,
'bordered' => true,
'striped' => false,
'condensed' => false,
'responsive' => true,
'hover' => true,
'floatHeader' => true,
'showPageSummary' => true,
'panel' => [
    'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY
],
```

]);
?>

This is the controller that renders the grid

```
public function actionTrackingcenter()
{
    $query = Truck::find()->where(['truck_status'=>5]);
    $searchModel = new TruckSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams,$query);

    return $this->render('trackingcenter/index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);

}
```

Could someone give a direction on how i can achieve the automatic change

Comment: Have you thought about JavaScript (jQuery for example) ?

Comment: you need to use pjax here's  an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhblqEROLWo

Comment: thanks i get the concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below with set-time-interval with jQuery

```
<?php 

$this->registerJs(' 
    setInterval(function(){  
         $.pjax.reload({container:"YOUR_PJAX_CONTAINER_ID"});
    }, 10000);', \yii\web\VIEW::POS_HEAD); 
?>
```

This code will be place after your GridView code

This will be reload your Pjax grid every 10 second

Comment: Thanks i did it that way... Please answer for me this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873040/calling-a-function-on-grid-action-coumn-click