# Calling a function on grid action coumn click

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I have a grid in yii that has an action column with a custom button I would like to call  function when the grid button is clicked but i get an error

This is my code:

```
[
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '{approve}{new}{reject}',
        'buttons' => [
            'approve' => function ($url, $model) {
                return Html::button('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>', ['value' => Url::to('approvetruck?id='.$model->id),'style' =>'background:none;border:none;','id' => 'approve','onclick'=>'alert('.$model->id.')']);
        },
            'reject' => function ($url, $model) {
                return Html::button('<i class="fa fa-close"></i>',  ['value' => Url::to('checktruck?id='.$model->id."&category=1"),'style' =>'background:none;border:none;', 'onclick'=>'reject('.$model->id.')');
            },

        ],
        'dropdown' => false,
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
            return '#';
        },


        'deleteOptions' => ['label' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>']
    ]
```

After the grid i have(on the same page)

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
 function reject(id) {
   alert(id);

 }

 JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
 ?>
```

The first one approve doing the alert works but the reject which calls a function reject fails..
it returns an error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: reject is not defined`

How do i do this

Comment: hey GEOFFREY MWANGI, try the answer i posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have to use below code for register js

```
<?php 

$this->registerJs(' 
    function reject(id) {
    alert(id);
    }', \yii\web\VIEW::POS_HEAD); 
?>
```

that will add the js in head part and it may get the function which you defined